# How can I create a slice object for Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've tried to find a neat solution to this, but I'm slicing several 2D arrays of the same shape in the same manner. I've tidied it up as much as I can by defining a list containing the 'x,y' center e.g. `cpix = [161, 134]`  What I'd like to do is instead of having to write out the slice three times like so:

```
a1 = array1[cpix[1]-50:cpix[1]+50, cpix[0]-50:cpix[0]+50] 
a2 = array2[cpix[1]-50:cpix[1]+50, cpix[0]-50:cpix[0]+50] 
a3 = array3[cpix[1]-50:cpix[1]+50, cpix[0]-50:cpix[0]+50]
```

is just have something predefined (like maybe a mask?) so I can just do a

```
a1 = array1[predefined_2dslice] 
a2 = array2[predefined_2dslice] 
a3 = array3[predefined_2dslice]
```

Is this something that numpy supports?

Comment: `np.s_` produces a tuple of slice objects: `(slice(cpix[1]-50:cpix[1]+50), slice(cpix[0]-50:cpix[0]+50))`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes you can use [`numpy.s_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html):

Example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
>>> 
>>> m = np.s_[0:2, 3:4]
>>> 
>>> a[m]
array([[3],
       [8]])
```

And in this case:

```
my_slice = np.s_[cpix[1]-50:cpix[1]+50, cpix[0]-50:cpix[0]+50]

a1 = array1[my_slice] 
a2 = array2[my_slice] 
a3 = array3[my_slice]
```

You can also use [`numpy.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) in order to translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I love when learning neat new tricks like this :) Thanks

Comment: @FriskyGrub If you want to learn more about such tricks, I suggest you to delve into the documentation ;-)

Comment: And look at the value produced by `np.s_`.  It's just a tuple.

Comment: Why give these useful utility functions such cryptic names, esp the underscore that suggests something internal? History?

Answer (score 18):

You can index a multidimensional array by using a tuple of `slice` objects.

```py
window = slice(col_start, col_stop), slice(row_start, row_stop)
a1 = array1[window]
a2 = array2[window]
```

This is not specific to `numpy` and is simply how subscription/slicing syntax works in python.

```py
class mock_array:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(key)
m = mock_array()
m[1:3, 7:9] # prints tuple(slice(1, 3, None), slice(7, 9, None))
```

Comment: This answer is more elegant than the accepted one IMO.

Comment: numpy.s_ returns slice objects anyway. For 1-D slices the latter command might be more readable, but for higher dimensions I definitely prefer the former.

Comment: The definition of mock_array is really really close to what's behind np.s_ or np.index_exp, see the [source code of np.IndexExpression](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/c65bc212ec1987caefba0ea7efe6a55803318de9/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L758)

Comment: Order should be (row, column) instead of (column, row)