# Python / Numpy - Finding subarrays by average value and deleting (or replacing) them

Tags: python, numpy

this is my first post, I hope you can help me. I have 120.000 satellite images with 33x33 px and 6 channels (RBG + 3 near-infrared). We have 10.000 sections with 12 images each. (one for each month) Since a lot of them are filled with clouds, I want to find a way to get rid of them.

The images are in a Numpy array with the shape (10000, 12, 33, 33, 6) and I want to find subarrays of the shape (33, 33, 6) in which the average of ( : , : , :3 ) > 0.5 (some threshold of high RBG values indicating clouds).

As a first step, finding and deleting them would be helpful, but in order to keep the shape of the array for later training, I would need to replace them with one of the other 11 subarrays of that position.

I have tried nested for-loops with np.average, np.where, np.delete, and so on, but did not get really far (I'm a beginner).

Would appreciate any hints, tips, or solutions.

Thanks!

Max

Comment: Add another array of the shape (10000, 12, boolean, 6) which indicates whether the image is used. IMHO the better concept would be slightly different data structure:
[10000,12,{[12,12,6],flags}] where you use flags to store meta information about the image. In later code you check the flags how you want to treat the image.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want/need to do is to find which of the "10k-12-i" observations are not useful -- *e.g.*, (:,:,:3) < .5 -- for a later use, the best thing you have to do is to create another data-structure on the side to keep track of them.

To do that, you can use dictionaries. Since dictionaries accept *any* hashable object as key, you could use *slice* objects as *keys* -- to point to your RGB (sub-)arrays, and values could be a "useful/not-useful" flag.
That way, once you define your dictionary -- with all the keys and initial value ("useful", until you find out the contrary) -- you could relly entirely/uniquely on your dictionary to "loop" over your arrays.

> For slice objects, have a look here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html . This question on numpy slices may be of your help: [How can I create a slice object for Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917173/how-can-i-create-a-slice-object-for-numpy-array) .

Cheers.