# Pythonic way to slice an array using array of index of slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, slice

Is there an efficient way to access multiple slices of an array with a flexible number of slices ?
Example below with a for loop I would like to avoid, left and right arrays lenghts are variable...

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) 
left =np.array([0,5])
right = np.array([2,8])   
for i in range(len(left)):
   a[left[i]:right[i]] = -1
```

Comment: [Use slice objects to represent the slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917173/how-can-i-create-a-slice-object-for-numpy-array#57881698), store them in a list or array, and iterate over them?

Comment: You should use the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917173/how-can-i-create-a-slice-object-for-numpy-array#57881698

Comment: If the operation inside the loop was more taxing I would say generate the minimum set of slices so you aren't resetting elements you already covered

Comment: Those slices are discontinuous, so can't be represented as a single slice.  If you convert them to an array of indices, e.g. `array([0, 1, 5, 6, 7])`, you can get by with just one indexing operation.  But creating that array will be as expensive iterating on the slices.  Unless the slice lengths all match.

Comment: `np.r_[tuple([slice(i,j) for i,j in zip(left,right)])]` produces `array([0, 1, 5, 6, 7])`. It expands the slices into arange arrays and concatenates them.  It's proposed more for convenience than speed.